# Reload aync call on view state update

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have the following view:

```swift
struct SpriteView: View {
    @Binding var name: String
    @State var sprite: Image = Image(systemName: "exclamationmark")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            sprite
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadSprite)
    }
    
    func loadSprite() {
        // async function
        getSpriteFromNetwork(self.name){ result in
            switch result {
            // async callback
            case .success(newSprite):
                self.sprite = newSprite
            }
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is pretty simple: a user modifies `name` in text field (from parent view), which reloads `SpriteView` with the new sprite. But the above view doesn't work since when the view is reloaded with the new name, `loadSprite` isn't called again (`onAppear` only fires when the view is first loaded). I also can't put `loadSprite` in the view itself (and have it return an image) since it'll lead to an infinite loop.

There is a beta function `onChange` that is exactly what I'm looking for, but it's only in the beta version of Xcode. Since Combine is all about async callbacks and SwiftUI and Combine are supposed to play well together, I thought this sort of behavior would be trivial to implement but I've been having a lot of trouble with it.

Comment: You could try to load the sprite in the parent view when the onCommit() function of the TextField is being called. Then pass the sprite to the child via constructor. For that you need to have the @State sprite in the parent and if the sprite isnt loaded yet, you pass Image(systemName: "exclamationmark").

Comment: Hmm...that works, I believe. But imagine in the parent view I have many network calls I'm making to receive sprites or other data. Then I need to have that many @State sprites in the parent view. But I think your approach inspires a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't particular like this solution since it requires creating a new `ObservableObject` but this how I ended up doing it:

```swift
class SpriteLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sprite: Image = Image(systemName: "exclamationmark")
    
    func loadSprite(name: String) {
        // async function
        self.sprite = Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var name: String

    @State var spriteLoader = SpriteLoader()

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(spriteLoader: spriteLoader)
        TextField(name, text: $name, onCommit: {
            spriteLoader.loadSprite(name: name)
        })
    }
}

struct SpriteView: View {
    @ObservedObject var spriteLoader: SpriteLoader
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            spriteLoader.sprite
        }
    }
}
```

Old answer:

I think the best way to do this is as follows:

Parent view:

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var name: String

    @State spriteView = SpriteView()

    var body: some View {
        spriteView
        TextField(value: $name, onCommit: {
            spriteView.loadSprite(name)
        })
    }
```

And then the sprite view won't even need the `@Binding name` member.

Comment: Having a child view as a member in the parent looks really odd. Does this even work? You are treating the SpriteView as a reference type, which it is not, as views are structs. Generally you should look on views as a function of some state. I think i would create an @ObservableObject which encapsulates the logic of retrieving and storing the sprite and let that serve as the state for your SpriteView.

Comment: Yeahh u right it didn't work. It did let me declare the struct as a State, but since it was a struct, calling a mutating func reloaded the struct with the same initial sprite, though there was no debug error. I've updated the answer.